# Play2 Maven Plugin - Server not running?

Tags: maven-3, playframework-2.2

I'm using the Play2 Maven plugin for one of my project and when I tried to start or run my project using the mvn play2:run command, I get to see that the build was successful, but when I tried to access the application url, I do not see anything (probably a 404). Any ideas as what is wrong?

```
--- (Running the application from SBT, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

[info] play - Listening for HTTP on /0.0.0.0:9000

(Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)


[success] Total time: 1 s, completed Mar 16, 2014 4:55:43 PM
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 8.855s
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Mar 16 16:55:43 CET 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/114M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It says to hit Ctrl+D to stop the server, but how can I stop a server that is probably not running? Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Strangely, this does not happen on my Windows machine. I do not understand why this behavior occurs only on Mac OS? On my windows machine the command prompt waits for my message to do a Ctrl+D if I want to stop the running server.